# PySpark: How to fix WARN WindowExec errors when trying to build a Map from a Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, warnings, python-unittest

I have a particular Dataframe with the following Schema:

```
root

|-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_metadata: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_usage_type: double (nullable = true)
 |-- last_updated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- filter_by_feature_metadata: string (nullable = true)
 |-- metric_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- calculation_plan: integer (nullable = false)
```

I want to make a simple map of this dataframe using the following command:

```
dataframe_map = dataframe.select("metric_type", "calculation_plan").distinct().orderBy("calculation_plan")
```

Technically this works, but I am getting spammed in the console output with the following log statements:

```
23/05/05 07:02:56 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:02:56 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:02:59 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:02:59 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/05/05 07:03:00 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

Is there a better way to build this map? I should say this is for purposes of unittesting/verifying my transformation logic.